# Making a local bind mount in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My team is using `docker-compose` for our project's container.

Previously, while we were learning how Docker works, we were just using `docker`. In `docker`, I could instantly see my local changes on my local deployment by attaching a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to the container when I run it on the command line.

Now, using `docker-compose`, there doesn't seem to be any such option - my workflow is `docker-compose up` with little opportunity for deviation. I believe I can specify a bind mount [as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) in our `docker-compose.yaml`. But that's not really what I'm looking for.

I'd like to be able to specify a local, personal, temporary bind mount without having to modify my team's `docker-compose.yaml` or commit my personal preferences to vc. How can I specify my bind mount from command line, or equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), there doesn't seem to be such an option from the commandline.

One way to get similar behavior to what you want is to make a second docker-compose file with the personal options. If you name it `docker-compose.override.yaml`, it will be picked up automatically. Otherwise, you can use the `-f` flag to load it, like so

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.user.yaml up -d
```

More details for using multiple docker-compose files are [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) (thanks @Sysix).

You could put this filename into gitignore.

Comment: here it is also documented: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files

Comment: Thanks @Sysix, I'll include the link in my answer.